# Find names of top-n columns in each pandas dataframe row and replace with top1 or top2

Tags: python, pandas, ranking

I get the following errors below. I was trying to implement the code below and relay the return df ranking into the original Av_ret_rank df to result in :

Top1 - XLE (1)

Top2 - XLK (1)

all the rest of the columns are at 0 only for that datetime

My goal is to fill the Av_ret_rank2 df for each datetimeindex row :

```
             XLP    XLE     XLV     XLI     XLB     XLK     IYT     XLU         
Date                                            
2018-06-10    0     1       0       0        0      1       0       0
```

In [Find names of top-n highest-value columns in each pandas dataframe row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955182/find-names-of-top-n-highest-value-columns-in-each-pandas-dataframe-row) where

```
   top1 top2 top3
id               
1    p2   p4   p3
2    p4   p3   p2
3    p3   p4   p2
4    p2   p3   p1
5    p4   p3   p2
```

My code doesn't work :
Original Av_ret_rank df -

```
             XLP    XLE     XLV     XLI     XLB     XLK     IYT     XLU         
Date                                            
2018-06-10  -6.7    15.4    3.1     6.0     4.2     13.2    10.9    -2.3    
2018-07-10  -1.7    11.4    3.7     0.3     3.2     13.2    2.2      2.3
........
```

My code :

```
nlargest=3
order= np.argsort(-Av_ret_rank.values,axis=1)[:,:nlargest]
result=pd.DataFrame(Av_ret_rank.columns[order],columns=['top{}'.format(i)  for i in range(1,nlargest+1)],index=Av_ret_rank)
result
```

Here are my errors :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    398                         if cls is not object \
    399                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 400                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    401 
    402             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    693     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    694     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 695     output = repr(obj)
    696     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    697         if idx:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in __repr__(self)
     80         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
     81         """
---> 82         return str(self)
     83 
     84 

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in __str__(self)
     59 
     60         if compat.PY3:
---> 61             return self.__unicode__()
     62         return self.__bytes__()
     63 

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __unicode__(self)
   661             width = None
   662         self.to_string(buf=buf, max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
--> 663                        line_width=width, show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
    664 
    665         return buf.getvalue()

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_string(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, line_width, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions)
   1966                                            max_cols=max_cols,
   1967                                            show_dimensions=show_dimensions)
-> 1968         formatter.to_string()
   1969 
   1970         if buf is None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in to_string(self)
    609         else:
    610 
--> 611             strcols = self._to_str_columns()
    612             if self.line_width is None:  # no need to wrap around just print
    613                 # the whole frame

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _to_str_columns(self)
    518         # may include levels names also
    519 
--> 520         str_index = self._get_formatted_index(frame)
    521 
    522         if not is_list_like(self.header) and not self.header:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _get_formatted_index(self, frame)
    822                                      names=show_index_names, formatter=fmt)
    823         else:
--> 824             fmt_index = [index.format(name=show_index_names, formatter=fmt)]
    825         fmt_index = [tuple(_make_fixed_width(list(x), justify='left',
    826                                              minimum=(self.col_space or 0),

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in format(self, name, formatter, **kwargs)
   2363             return header + list(self.map(formatter))
   2364 
-> 2365         return self._format_with_header(header, **kwargs)
   2366 
   2367     def _format_with_header(self, header, na_rep='NaN', **kwargs):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _format_with_header(self, header, na_rep, **kwargs)
   2388 
   2389         else:
-> 2390             result = _trim_front(format_array(values, None, justify='left'))
   2391         return header + result
   2392 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify, decimal)
   890                         space=space, justify=justify, decimal=decimal)
    891 
--> 892     return fmt_obj.get_result()
    893 
    894 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in get_result(self)
    910 
    911     def get_result(self):
--> 912         fmt_values = self._format_strings()
    913         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)
    914 

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _format_strings(self)
   1098             return [self.formatter(x) for x in self.values]
   1099 
-> 1100         return list(self.get_result_as_array())
   1101 
   1102 

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in get_result_as_array(self)
   1062             float_format = lambda value: self.float_format % value
   1063 
-> 1064         formatted_values = format_values_with(float_format)
   1065 
   1066         if not self.fixed_width:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in format_values_with(float_format)
   1047 
   1048             if self.fixed_width:
-> 1049                 return _trim_zeros(values, self.na_rep)
   1050 
   1051             return values

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _trim_zeros(str_floats, na_rep)
   1401                 not (any(('e' in x) or ('E' in x) for x in non_na)))
   1402 
-> 1403     while _cond(trimmed):
   1404         trimmed = [x[:-1] if x != na_rep else x for x in trimmed]
   1405 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _cond(values)
   1397 
   1398     def _cond(values):
-> 1399         non_na = [x for x in values if x != na_rep]
   1400         return (len(non_na) > 0 and all(x.endswith('0') for x in non_na) and
   1401                 not (any(('e' in x) or ('E' in x) for x in non_na)))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1397 
   1398     def _cond(values):
-> 1399         non_na = [x for x in values if x != na_rep]
   1400         return (len(non_na) > 0 and all(x.endswith('0') for x in non_na) and
   1401                 not (any(('e' in x) or ('E' in x) for x in non_na)))

 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _repr_html_(self)
    694 
    695             return self.to_html(max_rows=max_rows, max_cols=max_cols,
--> 696                                 show_dimensions=show_dimensions, notebook=True)
    697         else:
    698             return None

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_html(self, buf, columns, col_space, header, index, na_rep, formatters, float_format, sparsify, index_names, justify, bold_rows, classes, escape, max_rows, max_cols, show_dimensions, notebook, decimal, border, table_id)
   2032                                            decimal=decimal, table_id=table_id)
   2033         # TODO: a generic formatter wld b in DataFrameFormatter
-> 2034         formatter.to_html(classes=classes, notebook=notebook, border=border)
   2035 
   2036         if buf is None:

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in to_html(self, classes, notebook, border)
    749                                       table_id=self.table_id)
    750         if hasattr(self.buf, 'write'):
--> 751             html_renderer.write_result(self.buf)
    752         elif isinstance(self.buf, compat.string_types):
    753             with open(self.buf, 'w') as f:

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\html.py in write_result(self, buf)
    178         indent += self.indent_delta
    179         indent = self._write_header(indent)
--> 180         indent = self._write_body(indent)
    181 
    182         self.write('</table>', indent)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\html.py in _write_body(self, indent)
    341                 self._write_hierarchical_rows(fmt_values, indent)
    342             else:
--> 343                 self._write_regular_rows(fmt_values, indent)
    344         else:
    345             for i in range(min(len(self.frame), self.max_rows)):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\html.py in _write_regular_rows(self, fmt_values, indent)
    363             index_values = self.fmt.tr_frame.index.map(fmt)
    364         else:
--> 365             index_values = self.fmt.tr_frame.index.format()
    366 
    367         row = []

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in format(self, name, formatter, **kwargs)
   2363             return header + list(self.map(formatter))
   2364 
-> 2365         return self._format_with_header(header, **kwargs)
   2366 
   2367     def _format_with_header(self, header, na_rep='NaN', **kwargs):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _format_with_header(self, header, na_rep, **kwargs)
   2388 
   2389         else:
-> 2390             result = _trim_front(format_array(values, None, justify='left'))
   2391         return header + result
   2392 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify, decimal)
    890                         space=space, justify=justify, decimal=decimal)
    891 
--> 892     return fmt_obj.get_result()
    893 
    894 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in get_result(self)
    910 
    911     def get_result(self):
--> 912         fmt_values = self._format_strings()
    913         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)
    914 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _format_strings(self)
   1098             return [self.formatter(x) for x in self.values]
   1099 
-> 1100         return list(self.get_result_as_array())
   1101 
   1102 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in get_result_as_array(self)
   1062             float_format = lambda value: self.float_format % value
   1063 
-> 1064         formatted_values = format_values_with(float_format)
   1065 
   1066         if not self.fixed_width:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in format_values_with(float_format)
   1047 
   1048             if self.fixed_width:
-> 1049                 return _trim_zeros(values, self.na_rep)
   1050 
   1051             return values

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _trim_zeros(str_floats, na_rep)
   1401                 not (any(('e' in x) or ('E' in x) for x in non_na)))
   1402 
-> 1403     while _cond(trimmed):
   1404         trimmed = [x[:-1] if x != na_rep else x for x in trimmed]
   1405 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in _cond(values)
   1397 
   1398     def _cond(values):
-> 1399         non_na = [x for x in values if x != na_rep]
   1400         return (len(non_na) > 0 and all(x.endswith('0') for x in non_na) and
   1401                 not (any(('e' in x) or ('E' in x) for x in non_na)))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1397 
   1398     def _cond(values):
-> 1399         non_na = [x for x in values if x != na_rep]
   1400         return (len(non_na) > 0 and all(x.endswith('0') for x in non_na) and
   1401                 not (any(('e' in x) or ('E' in x) for x in non_na)))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented in the question you reference works fine. There are only 2 subsequent steps:

1. One-hot encode, for instance via the `sklearn` library;
2. Reindex columns to include columns not in the "top 2".

The second step assumes for some reason you need to store the "top 3" values in the first step. Here's a working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

df = pd.DataFrame({'XLP': [-6.7, 1.7], 'XLE': [15.4, 11.4],
                   'XLV': [3.1, 3.7], 'XLI': [6.0, 0.3],
                   'XLB': [4.2, 3.2], 'XLK': [13.2, 13.2],
                   'IYT': [10.9, 2.2], 'XLU': [-2.3, 2.3]},
                  index=['2018-06-10', '2018-07-10'])

nlargest = 3
order = np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, :nlargest]
result = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[order], 
                      columns=['top{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, nlargest+1)],
                      index=df.index)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

res = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(result.iloc[:, :2].values),
                   columns=mlb.classes_,
                   index=result.index)

res = res.reindex(df.columns, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(res)

            XLP  XLE  XLV  XLI  XLB  XLK  IYT  XLU
2018-06-10    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
2018-07-10    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
```