# Returning the highest and lowest correlations from a correlation matrix in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a bunch of stock data, and I am trying to build a dataframe that takes the top two, and bottom stocks from a correlation matrix, and also their actual correlation.

Let's say the matrix, `corr` looks like this:

```
  A    B    C    D    E
A 1.00 0.65 0.31 0.94 0.55
B 0.87 1.00 0.96 0.67 0.41
C 0.95 0.88 1.00 0.72 0.69
D 0.64 0.84 0.99 1.00 0.78
E 0.71 0.62 0.89 0.32 1.00
```

What I want to do is to be able to is return the best two, and least correlated stocks, and their correlation, for Stock A, B, C, D & E, while dropping the obvious 1.00 correlation each stock has to itself.

The resulting dataframe, or whatever is easiest to display this is would look like this:

```
Stock 1st 1st_Val 2nd 2nd_Val Last Last_Val
A     D   0.94    B   0.65    C    0.31
B     C   0.96    A   0.87    E    0.41
C     A   0.95    B   0.88    E    0.69
D     C   0.99    B   0.84    A    0.64
E     C   0.89    A   0.71    D    0.32
```

With my attempts so far I have been able to look through and return the relevant stock names using `corr[stock].nlargest().index[0:].tolist()`, and then taking `[1]`, `[2]` and `[-1]` from each list and sticking them in a dictionary and building the dataframe from there. But I'm unable to return the correlation value and I suspect I'm not doing this in the most efficient way anyway.

Any help really appreciated, cheers

Comment: Shouldn't a correlation matrix be symmetric? Or is your given example just an example matrix?

Comment: correlation matrices can be asymmetric, quite common in financial data

Comment: @Gio correlation matrices can never be asymmetric. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Correlation_matrix): *Because the covariance of the i-th random variable with the j-th one is the same thing as the covariance of the j-th random variable with the i-th random variable, **every covariance matrix is symmetric**.* I know that is for Covariance matrices, but the same applies.

Comment: See also: [Why is a correlation matrix symmetric?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31338/why-is-a-correlation-matrix-symmetric)

Comment: @pault can't find the papers I had in mind but here are others work (quite cited so I assume trustworthy) [paper1](https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/aang/papers/corr.pdf), [paper2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjb/e2012-30085-3). Another example is the correlation of price volatility with price movement. For a given change in price (P), volatility goes up more if the sign of P is negative. (i.e. given a stock with value `X` it that stock goes down of 10$ it will increase volatility more than if the same stock goes up of 10$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conditions are hard to generalize into one command, but here is one approach you can take.

#### Remove the diagonal

```
import numpy as np
np.fill_diagonal(corr.values, np.nan)
print(corr)
#      A     B     C     D     E
#A   NaN  0.65  0.31  0.94  0.55
#B  0.87   NaN  0.96  0.67  0.41
#C  0.95  0.88   NaN  0.72  0.69
#D  0.64  0.84  0.99   NaN  0.78
#E  0.71  0.62  0.89  0.32   NaN
```

#### Find Top 2 and Bottom Column Names

You can use the answer on [Find names of top-n highest-value columns in each pandas dataframe row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955182/find-names-of-top-n-highest-value-columns-in-each-pandas-dataframe-row) to get the top 2 and bottom one value for each row (Stock).

```
order_top2 = np.argsort(-corr.values, axis=1)[:, :2]
order_bottom = np.argsort(corr.values, axis=1)[:, :1]

result_top2 = pd.DataFrame(
    corr.columns[order_top2], 
    columns=['1st', '2nd'],
    index=corr.index
)

result_bottom = pd.DataFrame(
    corr.columns[order_bottom], 
    columns=['Last'],
    index=corr.index
)

result = result_top2.join(result_bottom)
#  1st 2nd Last
#A   D   B    C
#B   C   A    E
#C   A   B    E
#D   C   B    A
#E   C   A    D
```

Now use [`pandas.DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to grab the corresponding column value in `corr` for each column in `result`

```
for x in result.columns:
    result[x+"_Val"] = corr.lookup(corr.index, result[x])
print(result)
#  1st 2nd Last  1st_Val  2nd_Val  Last_Val
#A   D   B    C     0.94     0.65      0.31
#B   C   A    E     0.96     0.87      0.41
#C   A   B    E     0.95     0.88      0.69
#D   C   B    A     0.99     0.84      0.64
#E   C   A    D     0.89     0.71      0.32
```

#### Reorder columns (optional)

```
print(result[['1st', '1st_Val', '2nd', '2nd_Val', 'Last', 'Last_Val']])
#  1st  1st_Val 2nd  2nd_Val Last  Last_Val
#A   D     0.94   B     0.65    C      0.31
#B   C     0.96   A     0.87    E      0.41
#C   A     0.95   B     0.88    E      0.69
#D   C     0.99   B     0.84    A      0.64
#E   C     0.89   A     0.71    D      0.32
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to visualize the results but you don't actually need to fetch and work with the actual correlation values, then why not using a very simple [heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)? You could also play with the plot to have the numbers displayed on each square.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

 dict = {'Date':['2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04','2018-01-05'],'Col1':[1,2,3,4,5],'Col2':[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5],'Col3':[0.33,0.98,1.54,0.01,0.99],'Col4':[8,9.98,6,0.01,0.1],'Col1':[19,42,3,0.4,51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict, columns=dict.keys())
sns.heatmap(df.corr())
```

[image: heatmap]

Comment: hi mate sorry quick question, sns.heatmap(df.corr()) doesn't actually do anything for me as I'm not using jypiter, I'm just on pycharm, do I need to do .show() or anything? Just can't see to get the heatmap to show, cheers

Comment: @topbantz Most likely you have the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597116/seaborn-plots-not-showing-up)

Comment: had been trying sns.plt.show(), turns out I only needed plt.show() thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

A different answer relying more on the [modern pandas style](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining). I did not find a good solution for the second largest correlation. I'll edit the answer when I find it.

```py
### Create an example df
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"A":pd.np.random.randn(10),
                    "B":pd.np.random.randn(10),
                    "C":pd.np.random.randn(10),
                    "D":pd.np.random.randn(10),
                        }
                )


# Solution
(
df.corr() #correlation matrix
  .replace(1, pd.np.nan) # replace the matrix with nans
  .assign(  # assign new variables
            First = lambda x: x.loc[["A","B","C","D"], ["A","B","C","D"]].idxmax(axis = 1), # Biggest correlation idx
            First_value = lambda x: x.loc[["A","B","C","D"], ["A","B","C","D"]].max(axis = 1), # Biggest correlation
            Last = lambda x: x.loc[["A","B","C","D"],["A","B","C","D"]].idxmin(axis = 1), # Smallest correlation idx
            Last_value = lambda x: x.loc[["A","B","C","D"],["A","B","C","D"]].idxmin(axis = 1), # Smallest correlation
              )
)
```

I use the `.loc[["A","B","C","D"],["A","B","C","D"]]` such that the operations are made only on the unmodified data frame.

Output:

```py
          A         B         C         D First  First_value Last Last_value
A       NaN -0.085776 -0.203110 -0.003450     D    -0.003450    C          C
B -0.085776       NaN -0.110402  0.687283     D     0.687283    C          C
C -0.203110 -0.110402       NaN  0.017644     D     0.017644    A          A
D -0.003450  0.687283  0.017644       NaN     B     0.687283    A          A
```

Comment: You have a typo for `Last_value`. How could you extend this to get the 2nd highest value? Also the `replace(1, np.nan)` assumes that no two variables are 100% correlated (i.e. assumes no off-diagonal 1s).

Answer (score 0):

`corr.unstack().min()` -> to find the value

`corr.unstack().idxmin()` -> to find the indexes